# Flickering gif on rollover div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having trouble finding a solution to fix the flickering that occurs when I hover over this div to display a gif. [HERE](http://lilyclark.com) is an example of what I am talking about.

The code works just fine with jpgs...but not with gifs. I don't think it's an issue of overlapping or preloading.

I also noticed that the first 3 divs do not flicker when hovered. The issue only happens after the third div.

Does anyone know what might be causing this issue?

```js
function ShowPicture(id,Source) {
    if (Source=="1"){
    if (document.layers) document.layers[''+id+''].visibility = "show"
    else if (document.all) document.all[''+id+''].style.visibility = "visible"
    else if (document.getElementById) document.getElementById(''+id+'').style.visibility = "visible"
    }
    else
    if (Source=="0"){
    if (document.layers) document.layers[''+id+''].visibility = "hide"
    else if (document.all) document.all[''+id+''].style.visibility = "hidden"
    else if (document.getElementById) document.getElementById(''+id+'').style.visibility = "hidden"
    }
    }
```

```css
a:link    {
      text-decoration: underline;
      text-align: center;
      cursor:pointer;
      color: black;
      text-decoration: none;

    }
    a:visited {
        cursor:pointer;
        color: black;
    }
    a:hover   {
      color:black; 
      cursor:pointer;
      color: black;
          border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }
    a:active  {
      color: black;

    }
    #imagebox{
     width:100%;
     position: fixed;
     text-align: center;
        top: 50%;
        left:50%;

    }

    #list{
      top:25px;
      width: 40px;
      height: 35px;
      text-align: left;
     right:25px;
      position: fixed;
      background: url("../images/L.png");
      cursor:pointer;
      border-bottom:none;
    }

    }

    #list.hover{
      border-bottom:none;
    }
    #Style{
      position:absolute;
    visibility:hidden;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transition: 0s;
    -moz-transition:    0s;
    -o-transition:      0s;


    }
    #StyleX {
    position:absolute;
    visibility:hidden;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transition: 0s;
    -moz-transition:    0s;
    -o-transition:      0s;

    }
    #StyleY {
    position:absolute;
    visibility:hidden;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transition: 0s;
    -moz-transition:    0s;
    -o-transition:      0s;

    }

    #StyleZ {
    position:absolute;
    visibility:hidden;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transition: 0s;
    -moz-transition:    0s;
    -o-transition:      0s;

    }

    #StyleA {
    position:absolute;
    visibility:hidden;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transition: 0s;
    -moz-transition:    0s;
    -o-transition:      0s;

    }

    #StyleB {
    position:absolute;
    visibility:hidden;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transition: 0s;
    -moz-transition:    0s;
    -o-transition:      0s;

    }

    #StyleC {
    position:absolute;
    visibility:hidden;

    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transition: 0s;
    -moz-transition:    0s;
    -o-transition:      0s;

    }

    #StyleD {
    position:absolute;
    visibility:hidden;

    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transition: 0s;
    -moz-transition:    0s;
    -o-transition:      0s;

    }
    #StyleE {
    position:absolute;
    visibility:hidden;

    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transition: 0s;
    -moz-transition:    0s;
    -o-transition:      0s;

    }
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,800,600,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="../images/favicon.png"/>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Lily Clark</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <script src="javascrip.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <a href="http://www.lilyclark.com/about" id="list"></a>

    <a href="#" onmouseEnter="ShowPicture('Style',1)" onmouseLeave="ShowPicture('Style',0)" id="squareone"><img src="images/V1.jpg" style="width:25px; height:25px;"></a><span id="pname">Column Vase</span><span id="date">2016&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;for <a href"http://www.feel.company">FEEL</a></span>
    <br> 
    <a href="#" onmouseEnter="ShowPicture('StyleD',1)" onmouseLeave="ShowPicture('StyleD',0)" id="squareone"><img src="images/V1.jpg" style="width:25px; height:25px;"></a><span id="pname">Gravity is Stronger Here</span><span id="date">2015&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;for <a href"http://www.landl.us">L+L</a></span>
    <br> 
    <a href="#" onmouseEnter="ShowPicture('StyleY',1)" onmouseLeave="ShowPicture('StyleY',0)" id="squareone"><img src="images/V1.jpg" style="width:25px; height:25px;"></a><span id="pname">Blinds Be&shy;tween Boul&shy;ders</span><span id="date">2015&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Jumbo Rocks, Joshua Tree</span>
    <br> 
    <a href="#" onmouseEnter="ShowPicture('StyleX',1)" onmouseLeave="ShowPicture('StyleX',0)" id="squareone"><img src="images/V1.jpg" style="width:25px; height:25px;"></a><span id="pname">Fli&shy;cker Ton&shy;ic</span><span id="date">2015&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;for Tilt</span>
    <br> 
    <a href="#" onmouseEnter="ShowPicture('StyleC',1)" onmouseLeave="ShowPicture('StyleC',0)" id="squareone"><img src="images/V1.jpg" style="width:25px; height:25px;"></a><span id="pname">Printed Shards</span><span id="date">2015&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;with <a href"http://www.tristanscow.com/">Tristan Scow</a></span>
    <br> 
    <a href="#" onmouseEnter="ShowPicture('StyleE',1)" onmouseLeave="ShowPicture('StyleE',0)" id="squareone"><img src="images/V1.jpg" style="width:25px; height:25px;"></a><span id="pname">Bound 2</span><span id="date">2015&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;for <a href"http://contemporary.org">The Contemporary</a></span>
    <br> 
    <a href="#" onmouseEnter="ShowPicture('StyleA',1)" onmouseLeave="ShowPicture('StyleA',0)" id="squareone"><img src="images/V1.jpg" style="width:25px; height:25px;"></a><span id="pname">Novacom/Basin</span><span id="date">2015&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;with <a href"https://slumdiscs.bandcamp.com/merch/slumdiscs-01">Slum&shy;discs</a></span>
    <br> 
    <a href="#" onmouseEnter="ShowPicture('StyleB',1)" onmouseLeave="ShowPicture('StyleB',0)" id="squareone"><img src="images/V1.jpg" style="width:25px; height:25px;"></a><span id="pname">Oh So Cards</span><span id="date">2015&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;for <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KT5nXzQLhDI">Budget Prom</a></span>
    <br> 
    <a href="#" onmouseEnter="ShowPicture('StyleZ',1)" onmouseLeave="ShowPicture('StyleZ',0)" id="squareone"><img src="images/V1.jpg" style="width:25px; height:25px;"></a><span id="pname">Ra&shy;king Light</span><span id="date">2014&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>


    </div> 

    <div id="imagebox">
    <div id="Style"><img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/GRld0uPxi1V1C/giphy.gif" style="width:70%;"></div>
    <div id="StyleX"><img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/GRld0uPxi1V1C/giphy.giff"style="width:70%;"></div>
    <div id="StyleY"><img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/GRld0uPxi1V1C/giphy.gif"style="width:70%;"></div>
    <div id="StyleZ"><img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/GRld0uPxi1V1C/giphy.gif"style="width:70%;"></div>
    <div id="StyleA"><img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/GRld0uPxi1V1C/giphy.gif"style="width:70%;"></div>
    <div id="StyleB"><img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/GRld0uPxi1V1C/giphy.gif"style="width:70%;"></div>
    <div id="StyleC"><img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/GRld0uPxi1V1C/giphy.gif"style="width:70%;"></div>
    <div id="StyleD"><img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/GRld0uPxi1V1C/giphy.gif"style="width:70%;"></div>
    <div id="StyleE"><img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/GRld0uPxi1V1C/giphy.gif"style="width:70%;"></div>
    </div> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Can't reproduce it on my machine. Maybe it's a good idea to preload your gif before displaying it.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `opacity` instead `visibility` you can introduce a small `transition` and see image blending (if they are different), for demo i added a `transform:scale(x)` on a few of them.

**Note**: you can reduce the numbers of selector you use on `ID` with [id^=startwth"] or you could also just add a commun class. **Notice as well that ID can be used only once**.

```js
function ShowPicture(id, Source) {
  if (Source == "1") {
    if (document.layers) document.layers['' + id + ''].opacity = "1"
    else if (document.all) document.all['' + id + ''].style.opacity = "1"
    else if (document.getElementById) document.getElementById('' + id + '').style.opacity = "1"
  } else
  if (Source == "0") {
    if (document.layers) document.layers['' + id + ''].opacity = "0"
    else if (document.all) document.all['' + id + ''].style.opacity = "0"
    else if (document.getElementById) document.getElementById('' + id + '').style.opacity = "0"
  }
}
```

```css
a:link {
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: black;
}
a:hover {
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
a:active {
  color: black;
}
#imagebox {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
#list {
  top: 25px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 35px;
  text-align: left;
  right: 25px;
  position: fixed;
  background: url("../images/L.png");
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: none;
}
}
#list.hover {
  border-bottom: none;
}
div[id^=Style] {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
div[id^=Style]:nth-child(odd) img {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,800,600,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="../images/favicon.png" />
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Lily Clark</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <script src="javascrip.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <a href="http://www.lilyclark.com/about" id="list"></a>

  <a href="#" onmouseEnter="ShowPicture('Style',1)" onmouseLeave="ShowPicture('Style',0)" id="squareone">
    <img src="images/V1.jpg" style="width:25px; height:25px;">
  </a><span id="pname">Column Vase</span><span id="date">2016&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;for <a href"http://www.feel.company">FEEL</a></span>
  <br>
  <a href="#" onmouseEnter="ShowPicture('StyleD',1)" onmouseLeave="ShowPicture('StyleD',0)" id="squareone">
    <img src="images/V1.jpg" style="width:25px; height:25px;">
  </a><span id="pname">Gravity is Stronger Here</span><span id="date">2015&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;for <a href"http://www.landl.us">L+L</a></span>
  <br>
  <a href="#" onmouseEnter="ShowPicture('StyleY',1)" onmouseLeave="ShowPicture('StyleY',0)" id="squareone">
    <img src="images/V1.jpg" style="width:25px; height:25px;">
  </a><span id="pname">Blinds Be&shy;tween Boul&shy;ders</span><span id="date">2015&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Jumbo Rocks, Joshua Tree</span>
  <br>
  <a href="#" onmouseEnter="ShowPicture('StyleZ',1)" onmouseLeave="ShowPicture('StyleZ',0)" id="squareone">
    <img src="images/V1.jpg" style="width:25px; height:25px;">
  </a><span id="pname">Fli&shy;cker Ton&shy;ic</span><span id="date">2015&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;for Tilt</span>
  <br>
  <a href="#" onmouseEnter="ShowPicture('StyleC',1)" onmouseLeave="ShowPicture('StyleC',0)" id="squareone">
    <img src="images/V1.jpg" style="width:25px; height:25px;">
  </a><span id="pname">Printed Shards</span><span id="date">2015&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;with <a href"http://www.tristanscow.com/">Tristan Scow</a></span>
  <br>
  <a href="#" onmouseEnter="ShowPicture('StyleE',1)" onmouseLeave="ShowPicture('StyleE',0)" id="squareone">
    <img src="images/V1.jpg" style="width:25px; height:25px;">
  </a><span id="pname">Bound 2</span><span id="date">2015&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;for <a href"http://contemporary.org">The Contemporary</a></span>
  <br>
  <a href="#" onmouseEnter="ShowPicture('StyleA',1)" onmouseLeave="ShowPicture('StyleA',0)" id="squareone">
    <img src="images/V1.jpg" style="width:25px; height:25px;">
  </a><span id="pname">Novacom/Basin</span><span id="date">2015&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;with <a href"https://slumdiscs.bandcamp.com/merch/slumdiscs-01">Slum&shy;discs</a></span>
  <br>
  <a href="#" onmouseEnter="ShowPicture('StyleB',1)" onmouseLeave="ShowPicture('StyleB',0)" id="squareone">
    <img src="images/V1.jpg" style="width:25px; height:25px;">
  </a><span id="pname">Oh So Cards</span><span id="date">2015&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;for <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KT5nXzQLhDI">Budget Prom</a></span>
  <br>
  <a href="#" onmouseEnter="ShowPicture('StyleZ',1)" onmouseLeave="ShowPicture('StyleZ',0)" id="squareone">
    <img src="images/V1.jpg" style="width:25px; height:25px;">
  </a><span id="pname">Ra&shy;king Light</span><span id="date">2014&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>


  </div>

  <div id="imagebox">
    <div id="Style">
      <img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/GRld0uPxi1V1C/giphy.gif" style="width:70%;">
    </div>
    <div id="StyleX">
      <img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/GRld0uPxi1V1C/giphy.giff" style="width:70%;">
    </div>
    <div id="StyleY">
      <img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/GRld0uPxi1V1C/giphy.gif" style="width:70%;">
    </div>
    <div id="StyleZ">
      <img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/GRld0uPxi1V1C/giphy.gif" style="width:70%;">
    </div>
    <div id="StyleA">
      <img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/GRld0uPxi1V1C/giphy.gif" style="width:70%;">
    </div>
    <div id="StyleB">
      <img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/GRld0uPxi1V1C/giphy.gif" style="width:70%;">
    </div>
    <div id="StyleC">
      <img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/GRld0uPxi1V1C/giphy.gif" style="width:70%;">
    </div>
    <div id="StyleD">
      <img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/GRld0uPxi1V1C/giphy.gif" style="width:70%;">
    </div>
    <div id="StyleE">
      <img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/GRld0uPxi1V1C/giphy.gif" style="width:70%;">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems like this could work, however, can you explain what you mean by:

"Note: you can reduce the numbers of selector you use on ID with [id^=startwth"] or you could also just add a commun class. Notice as well that ID can be used only once."

After the first two divs, the hover effect stops working. Each div has a different image by the way.

Comment: You use id="squareone" many times, you should turn this into a class or give each a different id :) for the selector see:https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors